# Is a connected component a group?

Tags: group-theory, connectedness, topological-groups, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a topological group. Let $C$ be any connected component of $G$. It seems that $C$ may not be a subgroup of $G$ unless $C$ contains the identity $1$ of $G$. However, is it true that $C$ has a structure of a group on its own?

For example, let $A$ be any finitely generated abelian group. Consider the character group $\widehat{A}:=\mathrm{Hom}(A,\Bbb C^\times)$. As groups, $\widehat{A}$ is isomorphic to $F \times (\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$ with $F$ is a finite abelian and $r=\mathrm{rank}(A)$. 
Is it enough to say that $\widehat{A}$ is a $topological$ group which has a finite number of connected components? 
It seems that each component is isomorphic (as groups) to a torus $(\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$ . And is it true that each connected component itself is a group?

Comment: It's a coset of the connected component of the identity (which is a normal subgroup).

Comment: I am aware of that the connected component of the identity is a normal subgroup. How about an arbitrary connected component?

Comment: An non identity component is not a subgroup: it doesn't have an identity, and moreover is not even closed under multiplication. As a topological space it is homeomorphic, however to the identity component.

Comment: So in the example above, each component is actually homeomorphic (not isomorphic as groups) to the torus $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^r$?

Comment: Yes. To obtain a homeomorphism, you can choose an element $h$ of the non identity component, and multiplication by $h$ gives a continuous map from the identity component to that component, with inverse given by multiplying by $h^{-1}$.

Comment: I see. As above, $\widehat{A}$ is isomorphic to $F \times (\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$ as groups. Are they homeomorphic?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I’m trying to understand your point. Let $C^1$ be the identity component. If $C$ is any component and fix $c \in C$ then $C=cC^1$. That is, for any $a \in C^1$, the multiplication $ca$ is an element of $C$ i.e., there exists $b \in C$ such that $b=ca$, and vice versa. Is this correct?